# How can I get a list of Azure AD Users in my PowerShell script within my Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, powershell-core

Some context: I have a PowerShell script that gets information about users and their licenses on Azure, and then saves that information to CSV file. It works locally. My goal is to have this script automatically run on Azure (I'm trying to do it in an Azure Function App) once a month, and then have the created CSV file be emailed to a specified email. However all I want to figure out right now is how to get the list of users so that the script can at least just run without errors.

I have very little experience with PowerShell and Azure Function Apps, so I'm stuck on a few errors I'm getting. I have spent the last few days troubleshooting to no luck.

Here is the beginning of the script that I can run from my local PowerShell:

```
Function main()
{
 #Clean up session
 Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
 #Connect AzureAD from PowerShell
 Connect-MsolService
 #Set output file
 $ExportCSV=".\DetailedO365UserLicenseReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv"
 $ExportSimpleCSV=".\SimpleO365UserLicenseReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv"

 #FriendlyName list for license plan and service - txt file on local computer
 $FriendlyNameHash=Get-Content -Raw -Path .\LicenseFriendlyName.txt -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertFrom-StringData

 #txt file on local computer
 $ServiceArray=Get-Content -Path .\ServiceFriendlyName.txt -ErrorAction Stop

 #Hash table declaration
 $Result=""
 $Results=@()
 $output=""
 $outputs=@()


 $LicensedUserCount=0

 #Get all licensed users

  Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.islicensed -eq "true"} | Foreach{

  #this is another function that handles grabbing the user info and writing it to the CSV file
  Get_UsersLicenseInfo

  $LicensedUserCount++
  }
 

 . main
```

With this script above, it requires some user input for entering credentials. I want this script to be able to run automatically in Azure without any user input, so I've been trying to modify it to do that. I found out that any commands with 'Msol' in the name don't work in Azure Function Apps/Powershell Core, so I found a different module that apparently does work.

This is where I'm currently at with the script to be run in my Azure Function App:

```
Import-Module AzureAD

Function main()
{
 #Clean up session
 Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
 
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "{my password here}" -AsPlainText -Force
 $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myusernamehere", $password)

 Connect-AzureAD -Credential $UserCredential
 
 #Set output file
 $ExportCSV=".\DetailedO365UserLicenseReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv"
 $ExportSimpleCSV=".\SimpleO365UserLicenseReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv"
 #FriendlyName list for license plan and service - hash table here
 $FriendlyNameHash= @{AAD_BASIC = "Azure Active Directory Basic"; AAD_PREMIUM= "Azure Active Directory Premium"; AAD_PREMIUM_P1= "Azure Active Directory Premium P1"; AAD_PREMIUM_P2= "Azure Active Directory Premium P2" }
    
 #array of strings, used when getting user info
 $ServiceArray= "MCOEV", "Cloud PBX", "MCOPSTN2", "PSTN International", "mcomeetadv"

 #Hash table declaration
 $Result=""
 $Results=@()
 $output=""
 $outputs=@()


 $LicensedUserCount=0


  
Get-AzureADUser -All | where{$_.islicensed -eq "true"} | Foreach{

 Get_UsersLicenseInfo
 $LicensedUserCount++}


}
 . main
```

First of all I'm not sure if I even need to authenticate if this script is running from within my Azure account. Second of all, and my main issue, is that when I try to run this script in my Azure Function App, I get this error:

[snippet of the azure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Gfw.png)

If the picture doesn't work, it says:

The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Connect-AzureAD' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.

2021-06-08T16:48:00.377 [Error] ERROR: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.Exception

I get that same error for the line with 'Get-AzureADUser' as well. I followed this guide: https://tech.nicolonsky.ch/azure-functions-powershell-modules/ to add the AzureAD module to my managed dependencies, but I still get that same error.

If anything needs clarification, let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, AzureAD needs to be imported a bit differently - it's been a problem for a while per [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232#issuecomment-647827971). This seemed to work for most people:

- Setting the application to run as x64 bit: Function App>
  Configuration > General Settings > Platform > 64 Bit
- Setting the app to run on Powershell 7 instead of 6 on this thread
- Use: `Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell`

Comment: Thank you! I'm at least not getting errors now, so I'm happy about that. I appreciate the help!